# User-control based program

Tags: c#, xaml, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I am trying to create a new Windows Store-app, but before creating too many user-controls, I will like to know something that I have no luck googling

If my program only have one page, and the code thereby is based by user-controls, could it then be possible to use GoBack, or should I implement my own way to do that?

And if I need my own way to override GoBack, can I then override GoBack in the Page, or should I override it in general for the whole app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're going to keep the same instance of your page and just switch the user control that is displayed then you'll need to reimplement the existing navigation framework. For it to work you need to be calling `Frame.Navigate()` to switch between different page instances.

To do that in your case you could still only have a single page class but instead of just replacing the user control inside the same instance you could call `Frame.Navigate()` with the same page class and then inside it display the correct user control based on the parameter that you pass in. In this case you can use the existing navigation framework to navigate between the page instances.

Comment: And then I can use GoBack as it is?

Comment: @The87Boy In the second case, yes, i.e. as long as you use `Frame.Navigate()` instead of just switching the user control on the same page.